# Hide and Unhide LongListSelector in windows phone 8

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

How to use toggle button to hide and unhide a longlistselector in windows phone 8.

Answer (score 0):

You could just change the visibility when the button is clicked.

E.g.

```
private void MyButtonOnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    myLongListSelector.Visibility = 
      this.myLongListSelector.Visibility == Visibility.Visible ? Visibility.Collapsed
                                                               : Visibility.Visible;
}
```